# Are there quotas for incoming requests to a Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, quota

I'm running an script that changes rows in a Google Sheet through URL access, deployed as a Web App, omething like `macroUrl/?sheet=SheetName&key=KeyName&value=ValueName`.

This works perfectly for what I need it but I'm unsure on the quotas imposed on it.

Really all I'm doing is using the `doGet` and `doPost` functions in the script to grab/push rows to the sheet, however I foresee myself possibly accessing it upwards of 50k times per day. I'm unsure how to test for the max number of requests that I can make and google's quota page is rather confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using spreadsheetApp then there are no quotas you need to worry, however you may exceed the total daily script execution time. see here for more details: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas

urlFetch quotas do not apply unless you are making the call to the spreadsheets api v3/v4 directly without spreadsheetApp.

Comment: What would an example of the v3 direct calls look like?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this 50k times per day, the quota you will definitely hit is the number of times you can call UrlFetch from within your script.

If you are calling UrlFetch from within Apps Script, there is a quota of [20,000 calls per day](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for GMail accounts, and higher if you're using Apps for Your Domain or Apps for Work.

You may also run into the daily limit for UrlFetch data transfer. Right now that stands at [100MB per day](https://script.google.com/dashboard).